# Moodle gradebook export

Tags: database, moodle

I'm trying to import student's gradebook marks from Moodle database, but I cannot find any details where category marks are stored or if they are calculated on the fly. If they are calculated, could I reproduce this calculation in a query?

Thanks

Edit: Thanks to Hipjea I've got my hands on ad-hock queries page. This is what I needed. But now I'm facing another issue: for some subjects the query does not return categories. It looks like gradbook setup is the same for all of them. Need some hing wht it could be. It looks like course is not liked to categories somehow.

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gi.itemname
FROM mdl_course AS c
    JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
    JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
    JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
    JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid
    JOIN mdl_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category
WHERE  gi.courseid = c.id
    AND gi.itemname = 'Cycle 1'
    AND gi.itemtype IN ('category')
    AND c.id = 123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use the existing Moodle class `grade_report_user` which can be found in `grade/report/user` in order to get the data.

Here is an example of its use :

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/grade/report/user/lib.php');

$gpr = new grade_plugin_return(
  array(
    'type' => 'report',
    'plugin' => 'user',
    'courseid' => $course->id,
    'userid' => $userid)
);
$report = new grade_report_user($course->id, $gpr, $context, $userid);
$report->fill_table();
```

By doing this, you will have a preformatted HTML table.

If the `grade_report_user` class does not totally fit your needs, you can copy it into your own plugin folder, rename it accordingly and modify it.

Alternatively, you could find what you need in the Moodle's Ad hoc queries page https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#Site-Wide_Grade_Report_with_All_Items

Comment: Thank you Hipjea! You are the lifesaver. It is what I need. I could not find this page quite a while. I use direct DB query.